# NameError: Cannot load database configuration: undefined local variable or method `“RAILS_MAX_THREADS”' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails app I've created. It uses Rails for the backend and frontend.

I want to deploy it to Heroku, so I've been following some steps to convert my SQLite database to PostgreSQL.

I got to the point where I need to remove SQLite code from my config/database.yml file and replace it with PostgreSQL specific code.

I've added different versions of PostgreSQL code I've found on tutorials into that file. However, once I have the new code in the file and then run rails db:create I get the below error:

```
rails aborted!
NameError: Cannot load database configuration:
undefined local variable or method `“RAILS_MAX_THREADS”' for main:Object
(erb):10:in `<main>'
```

Not sure what to do here. Searched the error and there was like one result for this error which had a solution that didn't work.

Another thing to note is that I recently ran bundle install after adding "pg" to the gemfile, installing PostgreSQL, and deleting gemfile.lock.

My database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch(“RAILS_MAX_THREADS”) { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
development:
  <<: *default
  database: development_nail_the_trail
test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_nail_the_trail
production:
  <<: *default
  database: production_nail_the_trail
```

My gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "2.6.1"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem "rails", "~> 6.0.3", ">= 6.0.3.4"
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "pg"
# Use Puma as the app server
gem "puma", "~> 4.1"
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem "sass-rails", ">= 6"
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem "webpacker", "~> 4.0"
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem "turbolinks", "~> 5"
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem "jbuilder", "~> 2.7"
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", ">= 1.4.2", require: false

gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem "byebug", platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem "web-console", ">= 3.3.0"
  gem "listen", "~> 3.2"
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem "spring"
  gem "spring-watcher-listen", "~> 2.0.0"
  gem "pry", "~> 0.13.1"
  gem "pry-rails"
  gem "faker"
  gem "omniauth", "~> 2.0.4"
  gem "omniauth-facebook"
  gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection", "~> 1.0"
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem "capybara", ">= 2.15"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem "webdrivers"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong kind of quote characters here

```
ENV.fetch(“RAILS_MAX_THREADS”)
```

It should be

```
ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS")
```